Algorithm enviroment and verbatim font
I try to properly structure my homework and my teacher is using algorithm environment for PL/SQL language (example below). The thing is when I'm using this environment  the font is not the same. How can I get the same result than his? 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{An algorithm with caption}\label{alg:cap}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Do\$\$
\State Declare
    \State number\_1 := 15;
    \State number\_2 := 85;
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}


I seriously struggle with this environment, I let a little morsel of a code latex test but as you can see with it all the lines are considered to number 0 and I don't know why and when I'd like to have some indentation I didn't success to have it. Furthermore a "=0" appears in the code without knowing why.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.


you are loading incompatible algorithm packages. Only load the packages you need for a specific document, not more. An error message in the .log file will inform you about already defined commands. Do not ignore error messages. There is no point in wondering were a mysterious =0 might comes from as long as there are still errors in your code. After an error, latex only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document, not necessarily producing sensible output.

you can can add \ttfamily at the start of the algorithm or change the font globally with \algrenewcommand\ALG@beginalgorithmic{\ttfamily}. However note that many algorithm styles rely on bold font to mark special parts of the algorithm, like loops, and not many typewriter fonts have bold shapes. You will loose this markup as shown in the example below:


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{An algorithm with caption}\label{alg:cap}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Repeat
  \State this
\Until{you finished.}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}


Given that you don't seem to use any features from algpseudocode, I'm wondering if some kind of verbatim environment wouldn't be better suited for your use case?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Algorithm}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73396/36296
\lstset{
language=C++,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
numbers=left,
numbersep=4pt,
xleftmargin=15pt,
frame=tb,
framexleftmargin=15pt,
frame=lines,
}

\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\ttfamily\arabic{lstnumber}:}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{mylst}{\hrule#1#2#3}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=mylst,labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=off,labelsep=space}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[
  caption={An algorithm with caption},
  label={alg:cap}
]
Do$$
Declare
    number_1 := 15;
    number_2 := 85;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}



Ok, I'm wonder if there's a way to force indentation cause my commands are not considered like something precede by a \ and so there's not indentation for the following lines. For example when you've written \Repeat and then you leave some space before writing "\State this" this space is useless because an indentation is automatically created by the command \Repeat

@gaby8gaby You are not using any of the formatting commands from algpseudocode. If you format your algorithm by hand, you will also have to add indentation by hand. Or maybe a verbatim environment would be more suitable for your use case if you don't use any of the macros from algpseudocode?

Indeed, I will not use commands from algpseudocode but I want to stay as close as possible to the teacher's presentation so I guess I need to use algorithm environment but I haven't a clue how to indent code in this environment. Commands like \quad or , are totally ignored.

@gaby8gaby Using an environment designed for the job will be much easier than wrestling with something designed to do a totally different job.

Sorry I see you lstlistings environment after I write you another message. But yes it's way better with that, thank you so much for your time !

@gaby8gaby You're welcome!
